# Xero API Reports endpoints unauthorised

Tags: rest, xero-api

I'm trying to make some GET calls through Postman to the following endpoint:
https://api.xero.com/api.xro/2.0/Reports/BalanceSheet

getting this error:

```
{"title":"Unauthorized","status":401,"detail":"AuthorizationUnsuccessful","instance":"674c99d2-0ae3-4940-b23b-aec74cef79ea"}
```

The docs say this is a user roles issue, and suggests "view reports" access is off, but I'm pretty sure that's all set up correctly:
[screenshot of user role options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lh0eO.png)

It works fine through the API previewer, so I can't see what I'm missing.

Any help?

If it makes a difference, I'm using Oauth2.0 route.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll likely be missing the `accounting.reports.read` scope.

During the authorisation process, when you direct your user to the `https://login.xero.com/identity/connect/authorize...` url, try including `accounting.reports.read` in `scope` query parameter (along with your existing scopes, of course).